# Keras Autoencoders - How to visualize the values of the hidden layer?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, autoencoder, keras-layer

I am trying to do a project where the values of hidden layers play a pivotal role. I am trying to use a sample autoencoder from this tutorial,
https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html
I am able to do the gradient descent and it is also converging, but I am not sure how to print the values of the hidden layer. When I use print state on the model.outputs, I get  tf.Tensor 'add:0' shape=(?, 30) dtype=float32, where 30 is number of nodes in the hidden layer. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be done using Keras functions as you can read here: (https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer).

In essence you build a function like this:

```
import keras.backend as K
output_func = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()],
                     [model.layers[1].output])
intermediate_output = output_func([data, False])
```